# mongoDB Error: assertion src\mongo\util\net\message_port.cpp:195

Tags: mongodb

I have an update statement inside a forEach function, the update works fine, the query is perfect and all but each time I run the query after 30-40 mins the query stops running and I get this error Error: assertion src\mongo\util\net\message_port.cpp:195.

I can see the newly updated values reflected but I have to run the query over and over to finish my updates.

My query looks something like this and the query is expected to update 90,000 documents

```
    db.school.find({},{}).forEach(function(x){
        //do some math
        switch()
       {

       }
      db.schools.update();
   })
```